# Condicional para seleção de registro

Tags: mysql, query

estou com uma dúvida para a seleção de um registro de uma tabela e gostaria de uma ajuda.

Um exemplo da estrutura da tabela a seguir:

idhistorico_profissional | idprofissional | funcao |    inicio    |    final    | situacao

```
 9     77       telemkt    2013-12-01    2014-05-01      NULL
 10    77       venda      2016-06-01       NULL          0
 11    78       pweb       2012-03-01    2014-06-01      NULL
 12    79       program    2014-02-01    2016-08-01      NULL
```

Estou com um problema para selecionar a ultima função exercida, quando uso max(), retorna sempre os valores com data. Por exemplo, no caso do profissional 77 a ultima função dele é de venda, que ele ainda trabalha atualmente, mas a busca com o max() me retorna a função de telemkt.

Alguma ideia de como poderia fazer isso?

Segue a query:

```
SELECT profissional.nome, funcao, MAX(final) from historico_profissional 
        LEFT JOIN profissional on historico_profissional.idprofissional = 
        profissional.idprofissional GROUP BY historico_profissional.idprofissional
```

Comment: Coloque a sua SQL na pergunta?

Comment: Pergunta modificada já.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT profissional.nome, funcao, final FROM historico_profissional 
LEFT JOIN profissional ON 
     historico_profissional.idprofissional = profissional.idprofissional
WHERE idhistorico_profissional IN 
(
    SELECT max(idhistorico_profissional) FROM historico_profissional 
    GROUP BY idprofissional 
)
```

Comment: Opa, assim deu certo. Só ordenar os dados no BD.

Answer (score 0):

faz o "max" na data de inicio. 
    SELECT DISTINCT *,idprofissional,funcao,Max(Inicio)
    GROUP BY idprofissional

Comment: Não deu certo desse jeito.

Answer (score 0):

está retornando o telemkt no lugar de vendas pq o telemkt tem data e o vendas está null
a função `max` vai considerar a data nesse caso

pela amostra de dados você pode fazer o seguinte, procurar os que a situação for 0 e, logo esses serão os atuais (últimos) e usar `max` para os que forem situação diferente de 0